# how Stop strange users from trying to connect to my SQL server db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security

I have an asp.net website on a server and the db MS SQL 2005 on another server, the last few days the website show me this error message:
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

When i opened the DB server i found in the event viewer i found that there is a lot of fail login to the sql server from strange IPs, which are not ours, i think they are trying to hack the db,
Note the db is window authentication.

My Question is, how to stop that?

Comment: Is there a reason there is outside access on your SQL box?

Comment: you mean the remote access? no

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best thing you can do is deny access to your server's SQL port on your firewall. The request will never reach your sever and you'll be good to go. You probably want to deny 1433 and 1444.

Comment: if access is restricted then how can you access it, he says db is on another server. maybe changing the default

Comment: jvenema almost certainly meant to deny access on the external firewall, not the firewall on the SQL server machine.  thus internal network access would still exist, but the wider internet would be unable to connect to it.

Comment: rmeador has it right on. Deny access to the external world; the question says explicitly that these requests come "from strange IPs which are not ours", which implies that there is a known valid range of IPs.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to setup your firewall to deny any access to the SQL Server from the outside world.  You'll probably also want to deny access to your webserver from the outside world on any port other than 80 and 443 (is SSL is used).  Otherwise you are just asking for your servers to be broken into (if they haven't been already).

If your servers are at a different site than you or your office setup a site to site VPN between your office and the servers so that you can access then directly.

Answer (score 2):

Restrict IP's or allow only some Mac's , look for a good firewall that can provide you with this functionality

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a compromise or someone at the very least "tinkering about" with either the Web/Apps tier or database. The latter manisfests itself if you've exposed a database instance directly to the Internet - I sincerely hope that you've not done that. If yes (drop a comment and I'll follow up off line) ..... appears that someone has initiated mulitple connect requests to brute force logon accounts. If you've a Password Policy that implements lockout then they've more than likely knocked it out. SQL Accounts? Hmm, if was me I'd try "sa" to begin with. Isn't it the web instance that can't find the database?

Checkout the principles from Chip Andrews site http://sqlsecurity.com. Also, is the IIS Config and underlying Windows O/S locked down?

Next Steps .....

How does your ASP App/Web Tier hook into SQL back-end? Via stored procedures or SQL on the fly? There is still opportunity for mis-use in either case.

For instance, in SQL2005 onwards, the more interesting Stored Procedures such as xp_cmdshell are disabled. If you have not removed the dll from the system you can still enable them i.e.

exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
exec sp_configure reconfigure
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
exec sp_configure reconfigure

And if you have SQL on the fly, then look through Input Validation Techniques recommended on this site.

Are there any areas of upload provided by the site?

If you've implemented Windows Integrated Auth, if someone has gotten to your SQL server by an interface presented indirectly via Web/App, they can then set themselves up as a Domain Admin and own your entire Windows estate.

Cheers. 
BTW On the IP front ..... 
FYI http://www.ripe.net/ in Europe and ARIN in the US (also samspade.org) may help determine those rogue source IP addresses. You may not be able to do an awful lot with the info if those IP's are registered with 1 of the big Service Providers like BT in the UK but you never know